# React Navigation How to pass to Tab navigator form Login Screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a router class. And Also, I have a Login screen. After login screen, I want to pass the tab navigator page.

This is my login Page

```
<Login.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false
  }}
>
  <Login.Screen name="Initial" component={Initial} />
</Login.Navigator>;
```

this is my app.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeBackgroundColor: "#212A39",
            inactiveBackgroundColor: "#212A39"
          }}
          initialRouteName={"MainMenuTab"}
        >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="MessagesTab"
            component={MessagesStackScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => (
                <TabLabel title={"messages"} focused={focused} />
              ),
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                <TabIcon
                  images={"messages"}
                  focused={focused}
                  iconName={"messages"}
                />
              )
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="MainMenuTab"
            component={MainMenuStackScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => (
                <TabLabel title={"Home"} focused={focused} />
              ),
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                <TabIcon
                  images={"mainMenu"}
                  focused={focused}
                  iconName={"mainMenu"}
                />
              )
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="ProfileTab"
            component={ProfileStackScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color }) => (
                <TabLabel title={"messages"} focused={focused} />
              ),
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                <TabIcon
                  images={"profile"}
                  focused={focused}
                  iconName={"profile"}
                />
              )
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

how is that possible. What is it's architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like that

```
<NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator>
       {Store.userToken == null ? (
         <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginStackScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
       ) : (
           <Stack.Screen name="MainTabNavigator" component={MainTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />)}
     </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

and then you have to create stack

```
function LoginStackScreen() {
  return (
    <LoginStack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Initial"}>
      <LoginStack.Screen name="Initial" component={Initial} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </LoginStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [switch navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/switch-navigator/)

I'm using it like that;

```
const InitialNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
{
  Login: LoginPage, // imported login page
  App: BottomTabNavigator //created by createBottomTabNavigator()
});

export default createAppContainer(InitialNavigator);
```

and when your login process success, navigate to App like that;

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('App',{user: loggedInUser}); // user is navigation prop
```

Comment: Thnak you so much. But it's actually old version react-navigation for me  :)